# How to access data on third page in php

Tags: php, html

I am new with php i facing some trouble for transferring data problem is as folow:-

**Page1.php**

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="page2.php">
<table>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="bankcode" id="bankcode" /></td>
      <td><input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit"/></td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

**page2.php**

```
echo value is $_POST['bankcode'];
```

But now i facing real problem, if i try to access `$_POST['bankcode'];` on third page it shows me an error

**Page3.php**

How to access page1.php's textfield data on this third page. Please give some solution.

Comment: use session variables

Comment: POST data value available to one page another page only ..if need you have store it in session variable

Answer (score 1):

> In order to access one page's data in another page, the data has to be
>   sent in **POST/GET** format. Or it can be stored in a **session**.
>
> Using **Session** is the best option in such cases. The data is stored
>   securely in the server, and you can access the data from any page you
>   want.

**page2.php** - *Store your POST data in Session.*

```
echo "Value is ". $_POST['bankcode'];

$_SESSION['bankcode'] = $_POST['bankcode']; // Data stored in session.
```

**page3.php** - *Read the session variable.*

```
session_start();
echo "Stored Session value is ". $_SESSION['bankcode'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php).

On **page2.php** you can start the session and set the bankcode:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['bankcode'] = $_POST['bankcode'];
```

Then on **page3.php** you can access the bankcode by:

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['bankcode'];
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to access the data in third page you have to set the data in session `session_start(); $_SESSION ['bankcode'] = $_POST['bankcode'];`